# How to control an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to preload my images and rotate them every 3 seconds.

I'm having trouble with the rotate and preload functions.  I need to preload my images when the page first loads and rotate them every 3 seconds.  I've tried having the images in an array and not in an array.  Nothing seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <!-- JavaScript files -->
    <script src="js/preloadImages.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/rotateImages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class "centered">
        <img src="images/banner1.jpg" id="idBanner" alt="idBanner">
    </div>
</body>
</html>


//JAVASCRIPT CODE//
window.onload=loadImage;

var images = [];

function loadImage(){
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}

preload(    
"images/banner1.jpg", "images/banner2.jpg", "images/banner3.jpg", "images/silhouette.jpg", "images/work.jpg", "images/firefighter.jpg", "images/event.jpg")

window.onload=rotate;

var count=0;

var bannerImages = new Array("images/banner1.jpg", "images/banner2.jpg", "images/banner3.jpg");

function rotate(){
    count++;
    if (count==bannerImages.length){
        count = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("idBanner").src = bannerImages[count];

    setTimeOut(rotate, 3*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a way to go...

```
const ImgLoad = [ { img: null, src: 'images/banner1.jpg'    }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/banner2.jpg'    }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/banner3.jpg'    }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/silhouette.jpg' }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/work.jpg'       }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/firefighter.jpg'}
                , { img: null, src: 'images/event.jpg'      }
                ]
    , ImgBann = [ 'images/banner1.jpg', 'images/banner2.jpg', 'images/banner3.jpg' ]
    , ImgRota = document.getElementById("idBanner")

var ItemBann = 0

for (let ref of ImgLoad)
  {
  ref.img = new Image()
  ref.img.src = ref.src
  }

setInterval(() =>
  {
  ItemBann = ++ItemBann % ImgBann.length
  ImgRota.src = ImgBann[ItemBann]
  }
  , 3000)
```

you can also use: (to make sure all images are fully loaded before any "rotation")

```
const ImgLoad = [ { img: null, src: 'images/banner1.jpg'    }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/banner2.jpg'    }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/banner3.jpg'    }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/silhouette.jpg' }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/work.jpg'       }
                , { img: null, src: 'images/firefighter.jpg'}
                , { img: null, src: 'images/event.jpg'      }
                ]
    , ImgBann = [ 'images/banner1.jpg'
                , 'images/banner2.jpg'
                , 'images/banner3.jpg'
                ]
    , ImgRota = document.getElementById("idBanner")

var ItemBann  = 0
  , ImgLoaded = 0

for (let ref of ImgLoad)
  {
  ref.img        = new Image()
  ref.img.onload = () =>{ ImgLoaded++ }
  ref.img.src    = ref.src
  }

setInterval(() =>
  {
  if (ImgLoaded === ImgLoad.length )
    {
    ItemBann = ++ItemBann % ImgBann.length
    ImgRota.src = ImgBann[ItemBann]
    }
  }
  , 3000)
```